# Get stderr in a variable and print it in realtime with a subprocess that may need to read from stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I have found many resources on how to get the output of a subprocess but none of them seems to answer my case.

I would like to run a long command within python, print the `stderr` output in real time and intercept it at the same time. The problem is that the command sometimes ask for user confirmation, I would like to keep that interaction possible.

When using `Popen` with `PIPE`, I am loosing the ability to interact.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write to stdin and read from stdout on long-running child process in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811303/write-to-stdin-and-read-from-stdout-on-long-running-child-process-in-python)

Comment: In particular look into answers to this question that use [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is for exactly this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know in advance the flow of the command.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily matter.  But it depends on the specifics.

Comment: What do you mean by the specifics?

Comment: What command you are trying to control, what it outputs, what inputs it expects, how you intend to provide those inputs, etc.  In general using pexpect is the right answer in your case.  Have you tried it?  If so, what didn't work?

Comment: Didn't try it. I am running ffmpeg with some log output I need to catch provided by a filter. Sometimes ffmpeg will ask for things, for example to prevent overwriting. I am not aware of anything else that ffmpeg would ask and I don't think there is, but I was still curious about that possibility.

Comment: You can run ffmpeg non-interactively, e.g. by passing the [`-y` flag](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Main-options).  There are also several existing ffmpeg wrappers for Python.  Just one for example: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: Yes that's right. So the answer to the question is that it's not directly possible using only `Popen` and `PIPE`.

Comment: No, it is, but it takes some care. Regardless, it's not even an issue if you disable interaction. The library I linked to above in fact just uses `subprocess.Popen` to call the `ffmpeg` CLI.